# UOW Waiting IBM DB2 memory usage

Tags: db2, db2-luw

We have been encountering lately frequent hanging of our database server. Initial thoughts is its running out of memory. Based on logs, just before this happens, the stmm would reallocate memory.

The application currently accessing the database is running on jboss eap. Checking the logs, the error returned is its unable to open connections.

Initially, we are trying to figure out why memory runs out. We noticed that jboss opens a lot of active connections, and would not flush then

```
  Application     Cpu%     IO%    Mem% Application                         Application              Delta          Delta
   Handle(Stat)   Total   Total   Total Status                              Name                RowsRead/s  RowsWritten/s
   ------------ ------- ------- ------- ----------------------------------- --------------- -------------- --------------
       17819(c)   0.00%   0.00%   3.59% Connected                           db2jcc_applicat              0              0
       21065(i)   0.00%   0.00%   8.38% UOW Waiting in the application      db2jcc_applicat              0              0
       21069(i)   0.00%   0.00%   7.78% UOW Waiting in the application      db2jcc_applicat              0              0
       21080(i)   0.00%   0.00%   9.58% UOW Waiting in the application      db2jcc_applicat              0              0
       21138(i)   0.00%   0.00%   8.38% UOW Waiting in the application      db2jcc_applicat              0              0
       21156(i)   0.00%   0.00%   8.98% UOW Waiting in the application      db2jcc_applicat              0              0
       21169(i)   0.00%   0.00%   3.59% UOW Waiting in the application      db2jcc_applicat              0              0
       21175(i)   0.00%   0.00%   7.19% UOW Waiting in the application      db2jcc_applicat              0              0
       21179(i)   0.00%   0.00%   7.19% UOW Waiting in the application      db2jcc_applicat              0              0
       21182(i)   0.00%   0.00%   8.38% UOW Waiting in the application      db2jcc_applicat              0              0
```

I was wondering wheter the Mem%total would mean that memory is already being reserved for this process despite it not being in active use? Could this be the possible reason why we always run out of memory?

Comment: If someone is in the same boat, what we did was we managed the stale connections in jboss.